# JavaScript RegExp pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like below...

```
var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1 p2 p3 p4" var4="p1 p2" var5=val5
```

Now how can I replace all the `white spaces` with `underscore` only inside `""` using RegExp so that the string looks like below...

```
var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2_p3_p4" var4="p1_p2" var5=val5
```

so that by using `.replace('"','').split(' ')`, I can get an array like below...

```
Array(
   var1: "val1",
   var2: "val2",
   var3: "p1_p2_p3_p4",
   var4: "p1_p2",
   var5: "val5"
)
```

**no jQuery please...**

Comment: That is not an Array. That is an object.

Comment: Array is an Object... I need an array... for better understanding I show it as Object...

Comment: @Derek Not really. I'm afraid it's a syntax error, or, more likely, quasiPHP notation

Comment: Wait, is the `var1=val1 var2=val2` part of the string, or is it just the "p1 p2.." bits?

Comment: @tjameson `var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1 p2 p3 p4" var4="p1 p2" var5=val5` is a string...

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you want to create the string from the array, or you want to create the array from the string?

Comment: @Derek array from the string... Jan Dvorak's tricks works greatly... what I need... have a look on his answer... hope you will understand what I want...

Comment: @BlackCobra - So "replacing the white spaces" is all you want to do...

Comment: @Derek yes... but only them you are inside the double quotes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this has been answered but I thought I'd share this regex using a positive look-ahead. This allows you to `replace` without using a callback.

```
var str = 'var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1 p2 p3 p4" var4="p1 p2" var5=val5';

str = str.replace(/\s(?=[^=]*")/g, '_');
```

To explain:

```
\s        match a space...
(?=       start of positive look-ahead
[^=]*"    ...which is followed by anything except an =, up to a double-quote
)         end of positive look-ahead
```

Then the `g` will repeat the search

Comment: This assumes there's no `=` in the quoted string

Comment: Correct, but as Javascript doesn't support look-behinds I had to hook onto something. If that is an issue for the poster then your answer is the better one.

Comment: When it comes to speed, you beat me with a wide margin (except in IE): http://jsperf.com/replace-inside-dquotes

Comment: Nice! I hadn't seen jsperf.com before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace each string within the input string by another string by replacing spaces with underscores within the string. You can use a replace with callback to do that:

```
var inp='var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1 p2 p3 p4" var4="p1 p2" var5=val5'

var outp=inp.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(x){
  return x.replace(/ /g, '_');
})

// var outp === 'var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2_p3_p4" var4="p1_p2" var5=val5'
```

Comment: Friend, please don't mind... garyh has better answer than you... hope you will understand...

Comment: @BlackCobra It's up to you to choose the accepted answer. Note that Garyh's answer assumes there's no `=` within the quoted string (and that there _is_ an `=` outside it)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = string.replace(/(=")([^"]*)(")/g,function(m,g1,g2,g3){return g1 + g2.replace(/ /g, "_") + g3;}).split(' ');
```

Comment: Same idea as mine, except I don't need capturing groups ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't really need them either, since their values are static.

Comment: @asad you answer is incomplete... your code return me `var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8" var4="p1 p2" var5=val5`... it replace only the first white space for `var3`... and `var4` is not even touched... and after split the string by `' '`, it returns me a horrible array... please check your code at least once before submit... you almost have completed the code...

Comment: @BlackCobra Just forgot to add a `g` flag at the end of my regex. Change this: `/(=")([^"]*)(")/` to this: `/(=")([^"]*)(")/g`, and it should work.

Comment: @BlackCobra How is this incomplete?

Comment: @asad Friend, because now it returning `var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2 p3 p4" var4="p1_p2" var5=val5`... have a close look at `p1_p2 p3 p4`... it should be `p1_p2_p3_p4`...

Comment: @BlackCobra In Firefox and Chrome I get the output array: `['var1=val1','var2=val2','var3="p1_p2_p3_p4"', 'var4="p1_p2"', 'var5=val5']`

Comment: @BlackCobra I've made an edit, does this version work correctly in the browser you're using?

Comment: @asad check the edit... as i can't edit less that 6 characters, I try to give a nice look to your code... besides, as i already accepted an answer, i have gave a up vote to your answer...

Comment: @BlackCobra I've incorporated your edit. If you were the one that upvoted all my other answers, please don't do that, that isn't what upvotes are for.

Answer (score 0):

### Choose the one you need:

***Object:***

```
var txt = 'var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2_p3_p4" var4="p1_p2" var5=val5',
    arr = txt.split(" "),
    obj = {};

for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
    var ind = arr[i].match(/^(.+)=/)[1],
        val = arr[i].match(/=(.+)$/)[1].replace(/_/g," ");
    obj[ind] = val;
}

console.log(obj);  //This will give you an object.
// {
//     var1: "val1",
//     var2: "val2",
//     var3: ""p1 p2 p3 p4"",
//     var4: ""p1 p2"",
//     var5: "val5"
// }
```

---

***Array:***

```
var txt = 'var1=val1 var2=val2 var3="p1_p2_p3_p4" var4="p1_p2" var5=val5',
    arr = txt.split(" "),
    list = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
    var val = arr[i].match(/=(.+)$/)[1].replace(/_/g," ");
    list.push(val);
}

console.log(list);  //This will give you an array.
// [
//     "val1",
//     "val2",
//     ""p1 p2 p3 p4"",
//     ""p1 p2"",
//     "val5"
// ]
```